# Difference between calling eval with and without promise

Tags: javascript, html, url, ecmascript-6

I have a question. I saw in spec operation [HostMakeJobCallback](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#hostmakejobcallback), it describes two cases with non-null and null active script. Also there are two examples with code:

- active script is non-null

  ```js
  Promise.resolve('import(`./example.mjs`)').then(eval);
  ```
- active script is null

  ```js
  <button onclick="Promise.resolve('import(`./example.mjs`)').then(eval)">Click me</button>
  ```

I am interested in first one example. Imagine the following structure:

- index.html
- modules/

  - a.js
  - example.js

**index.html**

```js
<script type="module" src="modules/a.js"></script>
```

**example.js**

```js
console.log("example.js is included")
```

**a.js (don't run with all cases together)**

```js
/// case 1
eval('import(`./example.js`)'); 

/// case 2
Promise.resolve("import('./example.js')").then(eval)
```

**In case 1**: `eval` won't throw an error and it will print `"example.js is included"`. That I think will be correct because `import` gets `GetActiveScriptOrModule()` that will be `Module Record`

**In case 2**: `then(eval)` will throw the error. And for some reason this code will think that baseURL is `"http://127.0.0.1:5501/"` but not the `"http://127.0.0.1:5501/modules"`

Why these cases are different? Doesn't `HostMakeJobCallback` save active script for the future restoration with his baseURL from module script?

**`eval('import("./example.js")');`**
[image]

**`Promise.resolve("import('./example.js')").then(eval)`**
[image]

Comment: @jfriend00 these examples specified in whatwg spec. `Promise.resolve()` is used for invocation microtask with `eval` function that must take `active script` for `ScriptOrModule` component. So may you explain me why cases that I described are different?

Comment: @jfriend00 you can test it, if you make that I showed

Comment: Right from your [spec reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#hostmakejobcallback): ***Without this step (and the steps that use it in HostCallJobCallback), there would be no active script when the import() expression is evaluated, since eval() is a built-in function that does not originate from any particular script. With this step in place, the active script is propagated from the above code into the job, allowing import() to use the original script's base URL appropriately.***

Comment: Do you have a real reason to be using `eval()` in a context like this?  Because if not, then this is really just an esoteric issue that won't affect regular code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am writing an article about promise and all that relates to it. So I need to understand how `active script` affects to handler sent into `then`. I already know a lot about promise and things that arounds it. But that thing with `active script` and `eval` send me into confusion. And I try to undestand it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'd read note that you emphasized. And there is my confusion: every function that will be sent to `then` will have `ScriptOrModule` equal to script record where it's been defined. So if we define function in the file where we are doing `then` operation we will get script record of that file. But `eval` initially has `ScriptOrModule` equal to null. So what does actually `active script` do in here? I thought that it creates new execution context and store `Realm` and `ScriptOrModule` states of the current execution context for the future invocation. So how will it apply to `eval`?

Comment: FYI, I've written a ton of code using promises and NEVER needed to know anything about this issue.  This appears to me to be a weird issue associated only or largely with `eval()`.  Are you seeing any application of this issue beyond with `eval()`?  Is `eval()` something you regularly use in a sequence like this in combination with promises?

Comment: @jfriend00 if you look at my examples, you will see that first case throw the error because it gets `Module Record` from `GetActiveScriptOrModule()` (look at this function it's very important). And I agree that first case throwing by the error. Second case it's from spec, before the script will have been ended, method `then` and particulary his `HostMakeJobCallback` must been completed. So on this stage we should save active script's record to `ScriptOrModule` to the new execution context that will be pushed when interpreter call `HostCallJobCallback`.

Comment: @jfriend00  Finally when interpreter calls handler `eval` it has outer execution context with component `ScriptOrModule` setted to `Module Record` and current execution context with component `ScriptOrModule` setted to `null` (because `eval` has initially `null` value). And here you won't get correct URL path, path that provides `Module Record`. Why? Idk.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have no doubt that you are a good specialist but as I said I need explanation to this for my article

Comment: I'm just suggesting that unless you're writing a specific article about `eval()`, you'd be better off spending words in your article about more generally useful things related to promises.  This is a weird edge case that appears to be specific to combining promises with `eval()` which is extremely rare.  And, on top of it, it will be very difficult for your audience to understand.  There are many more important things to teach about promises that are a lot more generally useful and easier to teach.  My opinion.  Your article, you decide.